# Update VIRTUAL GENERATED column with CASE

Tags: mysql

We've changed how our KPIs are calculated, but I can't update the table, but when I use UPDATE SET with CASE, it fails.

```sql
UPDATE casedetails SET targetCompleted AS (
CASE
WHEN paidDate IS NULL THEN NULL
WHEN completionTargetType = 'A' THEN DATE_ADD(paidDate, INTERVAL 4 WEEK)
WHEN completionTargetType = 'B' THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(paidDate, INTERVAL 2 WEEK), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
WHEN completionTargetType = 'C' THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(paidDate, INTERVAL 2 WEEK), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
ELSE NULL
END);
```

The error I get reads:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS (CASE WHEN paidDate IS NULL THEN NULL WHEN completionTargetType = 'A' THEN D' at line 1
```

The SHOW CREATE of the table is as follows:

```
| casedetails | CREATE TABLE `casedetails` (
  `delegateReference` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `renewalDate` date NOT NULL,
  `fatalDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `renewalStatus` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `iprType` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `territory` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `forms` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `agent` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateInstructed` date NOT NULL,
  `dateSentToDV` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateDataChecked` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateDataDoubleChecked` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateSupplierAssigned` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateSentToSupplier` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateInHand` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `datePaid` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCompleted` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateClosed` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCancelled` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `whoSentToDV` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whoDataChecked` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whoDataDoubleChecked` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whoSupplierAssigned` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whoSentToSupplier` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whoInHand` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whoPaid` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whoCompleted` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whoClosed` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `formType` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whoCancelled` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cancellationReason` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recordalStatus` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `graceStatus` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`dateInstructed` > `renewalDate`) then _cp850'Grace period' else _cp850'On time' end)) VIRTUAL,
  `processingWindow` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time') then (to_days(`renewalDate`) - to_days(`dateInstructed`)) when (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period') then (to_days(`fatalDate`) - to_days(`dateInstructed`)) else _cp850'Unknown' end)) VIRTUAL,
  `urgency` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`processingWindow` >= 21)) then _cp850'Standard' when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`processingWindow` >= 45)) then _cp850'Standard' when (`processingWindow` >= 5) then _cp850'Expediated' when (`processingWindow` < 5) then _cp850'Urgent' else _cp850'Unknown' end)) VIRTUAL,
  `payThrough` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`agent` like _utf8mb4'%Direct Payment') then _cp850'Pay Direct' when (`agent` like _utf8mb4'Envoy Supply Limited') then _cp850'Pay Direct' when isnull(`agent`) then NULL else _cp850'Agent' end)) VIRTUAL,
  `recordalType` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`recordalStatus` = _utf8mb4'Requested') then _cp850'Recordal' when (`recordalStatus` = _utf8mb4'Outstanding') then _cp850'Recordal' when (`recordalStatus` = _utf8mb4'Completed') then _cp850'Recordal' when (`recordalStatus` = _utf8mb4'N/A') then _cp850'No recordal' else _cp850'Unknown' end)) VIRTUAL,
  `targetDataCheck` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then (`renewalDate` - interval 21 day) when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then (`fatalDate` - interval 21 day) when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard')) then (`dateInstructed` + interval 2 day) when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Expediated')) then (`dateInstructed` + interval 2 day) else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `targetDataDoubleCheck` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then (`renewalDate` - interval 20 day) when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then (`fatalDate` - interval 20 day) when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then (`renewalDate` - interval 45 day) when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then (`fatalDate` - interval 45 day) else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `targetSupplierAssigned` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then (`renewalDate` - interval 18 day) when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then (`fatalDate` - interval 18 day) when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then (`renewalDate` - interval 45 day) when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then (`fatalDate` - interval 45 day) else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `targetSentToSupplier` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then (`renewalDate` - interval 10 day) when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then (`fatalDate` - interval 10 day) when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then (`renewalDate` - interval 18 day) when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then (`fatalDate` - interval 18 day) else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `targetInHand` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`payThrough` = _utf8mb4'Agent') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then (`renewalDate` - interval 4 day) when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`payThrough` = _utf8mb4'Agent') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then (`fatalDate` - interval 4 day) when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`payThrough` = _utf8mb4'Agent') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then (`renewalDate` - interval 14 day) when ((`iprType` = _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`payThrough` = _utf8mb4'Agent') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then (`fatalDate` - interval 14 day) else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `targetPaid` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`payThrough` = _utf8mb4'Pay Direct') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then (`renewalDate` - interval 4 day) when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`payThrough` = _utf8mb4'Pay Direct') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then (`fatalDate` - interval 4 day) when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` <> _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`payThrough` = _utf8mb4'Pay Direct') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'On time')) then `renewalDate` when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` <> _utf8mb4'Standard') and (`payThrough` = _utf8mb4'Pay Direct') and (`graceStatus` = _utf8mb4'Grace period')) then `fatalDate` else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `targetCompleted` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` <> _utf8mb4'Overdue')) then `renewalDate` when ((`iprType` <> _utf8mb4'Trademark') and (`urgency` = _utf8mb4'Overdue')) then `fatalDate` else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `targetClosed` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`fatalDate`) VIRTUAL,
  `kpiDataChecked` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (isnull(`dateDataChecked`) and (`targetDataCheck` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Holding')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateDataChecked`) and (`targetDataCheck` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Ready')) then 'Outstanding' when (`targetDataCheck` < `dateDataChecked`) then 'Outside KPI' when (`targetDataCheck` > `dateDataChecked`) then 'Inside KPI' else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `kpiDataDoubleChecked` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (isnull(`dateDataDoubleChecked`) and (`targetDataDoubleCheck` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Holding')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateDataDoubleChecked`) and (`targetDataDoubleCheck` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Ready')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateDataDoubleChecked`) and (`targetDataDoubleCheck` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (`targetDataDoubleCheck` < `dateDataDoubleChecked`) then 'Outside KPI' when (`targetDataDoubleCheck` > `dateDataDoubleChecked`) then 'Inside KPI' else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `kpiSupplierAssigned` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (isnull(`dateSupplierAssigned`) and (`targetSupplierAssigned` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Holding')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateSupplierAssigned`) and (`targetSupplierAssigned` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Ready')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateSupplierAssigned`) and (`targetSupplierAssigned` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateSupplierAssigned`) and (`targetSupplierAssigned` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Double Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (`targetSupplierAssigned` < `dateSupplierAssigned`) then 'Outside KPI' when (`targetSupplierAssigned` > `dateSupplierAssigned`) then 'Inside KPI' else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `kpiSentToSupplier` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (isnull(`dateSentToSupplier`) and (`targetSentToSupplier` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Holding')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateSentToSupplier`) and (`targetSentToSupplier` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Ready')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateSentToSupplier`) and (`targetSentToSupplier` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateSentToSupplier`) and (`targetSentToSupplier` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Double Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateSentToSupplier`) and (`targetSentToSupplier` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` like '%Assigned')) then 'Outstanding' when (`targetSentToSupplier` < `dateSentToSupplier`) then 'Outside KPI' when (`targetSentToSupplier` > `dateSentToSupplier`) then 'Inside KPI' else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `kpiInHand` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (isnull(`dateInHand`) and (`targetInHand` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Holding')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateInHand`) and (`targetInHand` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Ready')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateInHand`) and (`targetInHand` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateInHand`) and (`targetInHand` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Double Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateInHand`) and (`targetInHand` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` like '%Assigned')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateInHand`) and (`targetInHand` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` like 'Sent to%')) then 'Outstanding' when (`targetInHand` < `dateInHand`) then 'Outside KPI' when (`targetInHand` > `dateInHand`) then 'Inside KPI' else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `kpiPaid` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Holding')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Ready')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Double Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` like '%Assigned')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` like 'Sent to%')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Payment in Hand')) then 'Outstanding' when (`targetPaid` < `datePaid`) then 'Outside KPI' when (`targetPaid` > `datePaid`) then 'Inside KPI' else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `kpiCompleted` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Holding')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Ready')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Double Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` like '%Assigned')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` like 'Sent to%')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Payment in Hand')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateCompleted`) and (`targetCompleted` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Paid')) then 'Outstanding' when (`targetCompleted` < `dateCompleted`) then 'Outside KPI' when (`targetCompleted` > `dateCompleted`) then 'Inside KPI' else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `kpiClosed` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (isnull(`dateClosed`) and (`targetClosed` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Holding')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateClosed`) and (`targetClosed` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Ready')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateClosed`) and (`targetClosed` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateClosed`) and (`targetClosed` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Double Checked')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateClosed`) and (`targetClosed` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` like '%Assigned')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateClosed`) and (`targetClosed` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` like 'Sent to%')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateClosed`) and (`targetClosed` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Payment in Hand')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateClosed`) and (`targetClosed` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Paid')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateClosed`) and (`targetClosed` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Completed')) then 'Outstanding' when (isnull(`dateClosed`) and (`targetClosed` is not null) and (`renewalStatus` = 'Closed')) then 'Outstanding' when (`targetClosed` < `dateClosed`) then 'Outside KPI' when (`targetClosed` > `dateClosed`) then 'Inside KPI' else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `onTimeDataChecked` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiDataChecked` = 'Inside KPI') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `onTimeDataDoubleChecked` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiDataDoubleChecked` = 'Inside KPI') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `onTimeSupplierAssigned` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiSupplierAssigned` = 'Inside KPI') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `onTimeSentToSupplier` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiSentToSupplier` = 'Inside KPI') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `onTimeInHand` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiInHand` = 'Inside KPI') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `onTimePaid` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiPaid` = 'Inside KPI') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `onTimeCompleted` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiCompleted` = 'Inside KPI') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `onTimeClosed` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiClosed` = 'Inside KPI') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `dbtDataChecked` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`targetDataCheck`) - to_days(`dateDataChecked`))) VIRTUAL,
  `dbtDataDoubleChecked` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`targetDataDoubleCheck`) - to_days(`dateDataDoubleChecked`))) VIRTUAL,
  `dbtSupplierAssigned` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`targetSupplierAssigned`) - to_days(`dateSupplierAssigned`))) VIRTUAL,
  `dbtSentToSupplier` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`targetSentToSupplier`) - to_days(`dateSentToSupplier`))) VIRTUAL,
  `dbtInHand` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`targetInHand`) - to_days(`dateInHand`))) VIRTUAL,
  `dbtPaid` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`targetPaid`) - to_days(`datePaid`))) VIRTUAL,
  `dbtCompleted` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`targetCompleted`) - to_days(`dateCompleted`))) VIRTUAL,
  `dbtClosed` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`targetClosed`) - to_days(`dateClosed`))) VIRTUAL,
  `ipanType` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`agent` = 'Ipan GmbH') then 'ipan' when (`payThrough` = 'Pay Direct') then 'Pay Direct' else 'Not ipan' end)) VIRTUAL,
  `dvType` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`dateSentToDV` is not null) and (`whoDataChecked` = 'ADV')) then 'Auto DV' when ((`dateSentToDV` is not null) and (`whoDataChecked` <> 'ADV')) then 'Manual DV' when isnull(`dateSentToDV`) then 'Not DV' else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `agentefficiency` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`dateInHand`) - to_days(`dateSentToSupplier`))) VIRTUAL,
  `paymentStatus` varchar(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`renewalStatus` = 'Holding') then 'Unpaid' when (`renewalStatus` = 'Ready') then 'Unpaid' when (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Checked') then 'Unpaid' when (`renewalStatus` = 'Data Double Checked') then 'Unpaid' when (`renewalStatus` = 'Sent to DV') then 'Unpaid' when (`renewalStatus` like '%Assigned') then 'Unpaid' when (`renewalStatus` like 'Sent to%') then 'Unpaid' when (`renewalStatus` = 'Payment in Hand') then 'Unpaid' when (`renewalStatus` = 'Paid') then 'Paid' when (`renewalStatus` = 'Completed') then 'Paid' when (`renewalStatus` = 'Closed') then 'Paid' else NULL end)) VIRTUAL,
  `byDeadline` varchar(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`graceStatus` = 'On time') and (`datePaid` <= `renewalDate`)) then 'On time' when ((`graceStatus` = 'On time') and (`datePaid` > `renewalDate`)) then 'Late' when ((`graceStatus` = 'Grace period') and (`datePaid` <= `fatalDate`)) then 'On time' when ((`graceStatus` = 'Grace period') and (`datePaid` > `renewalDate`)) then 'Late' end)) VIRTUAL,
  `onTimeDeadline` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`byDeadline` = 'On time') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `lateDeadline` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`byDeadline` = 'Late') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `daysToClose` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`dateClosed`) - to_days(`dateInstructed`))) VIRTUAL,
  `daysToComplete` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`dateCompleted`) - to_days(`dateInstructed`))) VIRTUAL,
  `wasCancelled` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`dateCancelled` is not null) then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `paymentEfficiency` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((to_days(`datePaid`) - to_days(`dateInHand`))) VIRTUAL,
  `lateDataChecked` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiDataChecked` like 'Out%') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `lateDataDoubleChecked` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiDataDoubleChecked` like 'Out%') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `lateSupplierAssigned` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiSupplierAssigned` like 'Out%') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `lateSentToSupplier` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiSentToSupplier` like 'Out%') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `lateInHand` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiInHand` like 'Out%') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `latePaid` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiPaid` like 'Out%') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `lateCompleted` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiCompleted` like 'Out%') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `lateClosed` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`kpiClosed` like 'Out%') then 1 else 0 end)) VIRTUAL,
  `completionTargetType` varchar(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`payThrough` = 'Pay Direct') then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'AT')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'AU')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'BX')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'DK')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'EP')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'EUTM')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'FI')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'DE')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'HK')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'IE')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'NZ')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'NO')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'SG')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'SE')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'CH')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'GB')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'US')) then 'A' when ((`iprType` = 'Trademark') and (`territory` = 'WO')) then 'A' when (`ipanType` = 'ipan') then 'B' else 'C' end)) VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`delegateReference`)
```

I am wondering if my best course of action is simply an atomic drop and re-create the column, but as other virtual columns are dependent on it, it would be a total pain to atomic drop a whole bunch.

Comment: Please add the table definition

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: You have table called case details, I Would like you to publish its definition/schema Try typing show create table casedetails and copy an paste the result in the question

Comment: Done - thanks @P.Salmon!

Comment: paiddate does not exist in this table, so where is that coming from, ALSO the table definition provided looks more like the result of a DESCRIBE and is less useful than the result of a SHOW CREATE since it doesn't show on what basis targetcompleted is generated.

Comment: No matter the syntax error is set..as which should be set..=.But fixing this will cause a run time error because you cannot set a virtual generated column (it's not stored so how could you..). Can you explain why you want to run an update like this there does not seem to be any point to having the generated column.

Comment: Thanks for the help, P.Salmon. You're right about paiddate, it should be datePaid. The targetCompleted date calculates the target date for the case to be Completed, and the business wants to change how that target is calculated.

Comment: I've updated the above to show the `SHOW CREATE` and not `DESC`